# SQL Server Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB like this:

> ID | AccessCode

and the code is repeated trough rows.
I want a select that looks like this

AccessCode | how many entries are in the table matching this AcessCode

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
select AccessCode, COUNT(ID) as Entires
from YourTable
group by AccessCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select AccessCode, count(AccessCode) from sometable group by AccessCode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take care of nulls (id)...

```
select 
  accesscode,count(*) as total
from 
  t
group by accesscode
order by total;
```

see sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79fe2/1